# Recommendations on Triming Large Amounts of Text from a DOM Object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm doing some in browser editing, and I have some content that's on the order of around 20k characters long in a <textarea>.

So it looks something like:

```
<textarea>
Text 1
Text 2

Text 3
Text 4
[...]
Text 20,000
</textarea>
```

I'd like to use jquery to trim it down when someone hits a button to chop, but I'm having trouble doing it without overloading the browser. Assume I know that the character numbers are at 16,510 - 17,888, and what I'd like to do is trim it.

I *was* using:

`jQuery('#textsection').html(jQuery('textarea').html().substr(range.start));`

But browsers seem to enjoy crashing when I do this. Alternatives?

**EDIT**

Solution from the comments:

```
 var removeTextNode = document.getElementById('textarea').firstChild;
 removeTextNode.splitText(indexOfCharacterToRemoveEverythingBefore);
 removeTextNode.parentNode.removeChild(removeTextNode);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure about jQuery, but with plain vanilla Javascript, this can be done by using the `splitText()` method of the `textNode` object. Your `<pre>` has a `textNode` child which contains all the text inside of it. (You can get it from the `childNodes` collection.) Split it at the desired index, then use `removeChild()` to delete the part you don't need.

Comment: Very interesting!

Actually, i made a mistake above - it's a textarea... would this still work?

Comment: BTW, your last line can be simplified to save one doc ID lookup: removeTextNode.parentNode.removeChild(removeTextNode)

Answer (score 1):

What browser are you testing on?

[`substr`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substr.asp) takes the starting index, and an optional length. If the length is omitted, then it extracts upto the end of the string. [`substring`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substring.asp) takes the starting and ending index of the string to extract, which I think might be a better option since you already have those available.

I've created a small [example at fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FzxKe/) using the book [Alice's Adventures in Wonderland](http://www.gutenberg.org/etext/11), by Lewis Carroll. The book is about 160,000 characters in length, and you can try with various starting/ending indexes and see if it crashes the browser. Seems to work fine on my Chrome, Firefox, and Safari. Unfortunately I don't have access to IE. Here's the function that's used:

```
function chop(start, end) {
    var trimmedText = $('#preId').html().substring(start, end);
    $('textarea').val(trimmedText);
}
​
```

Comment: Very thorough and quick answer! I'm using FF 3.6 - let me try exactly what you're doing and see if i can repro. Every time I do it, it whites out the browser.

Comment: thanks. an infinite loop somewhere might be causing the browser to crash, or maybe some other processing is triggered when you click trim.